# Svcutil download

Tags: wcf, web-services

I've Micorosft Windows SDK on my machine but i dont have this folder :C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin. Also, the utility svcUtil.exe for generating web service proxy is missing.
Where can i download just svcUtil.exe file?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to have .NET 3.0 or newer, and the Windows SDK 6.0 or higher. You cannot download just svcutil.exe separately.

Comment: Yes, figured that out.Thanks for ur response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks marc_s for your comment inputs:

> You need to have .NET 3.0 or newer, and the Windows SDK 6.0 or higher. You cannot download just svcutil.exe separately. – marc_s